# IntelliJ - a few questions

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I just recently changed IDEs from Netbeans to IntelliJ-Idea. I like it much more so far, but there a few questions I have about it.

First off, how do I create custom code completion words? For example you could go into the Netbeans settings and create a template with a word, say 'syso', and you would type 'syso' and press tab and it would change it to System.out.println in the code editor. Is this possible in IntelliJ? I have searched the settings and googled it but I can't seem to figure it out.

Second, the tabs are a little irritating sometimes. When I open a new tab it places it right after the current tab selected, and it bothers me, is it possible to make it appear last after all the tabs?

Other than that, I am loving this IDE much more because of its amazing auto-completion and UI.

Comment: I would say it's better to ask one question at a time :) So maybe you can edit your question to be more focused by your first requirement (abbreviations) and edit the title, that way others can find it easily later and exploit from the potential answers. You can ask the other question separately then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your first requirement is covered nicely by IntelliJ IDEA.

### Live Templates

You can define Live Templates by opening the `Preferences`.

[image]

Then you can easily add or modify live templates. The good thing is they are grouped.

Now you can choose your desired group and then add a new live template.
[image]

Then you can define the abbreviation, for example `syso`, and edit the form like this:
[image]

Then you have to define the context this template applies to

[image]

### Default Live Templates

There are a multitude of default live templates already supported out of the box. For instance the one you want in this case is `sout`, which is provided by default. You can read more about this in [JetBrains Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html#d1438745e110)

Comment: Ah, thank you, this helps a lot. I think using ctrl tab will be fine for the tab ordering. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first requirement is covered by [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html).  These allow you to, on a per-language basis, add a little bit of templatable syntax and allow you to specify your expansion character to help with your development.

I will note that the `System.out.println` case is already well covered by both these templates and [postfix completion](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/); the former allowing you to type `sout` then <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get `System.out.println`; the latter allowing you to type your expression and *then* `sout` to have it wrapped in a `System.out.println` statement.

The piece about tab ordering is an issue I haven't encountered before.  More times than not I find myself using the Recent Files menu (CTRL + E or Command + E).  I don't believe there's a way to enforce ordering of tabs.

Comment: Also note that with nice navigation features in IDEA, you never have to care about the order of tabs open in editor. You can easily navigate between tabs by pressing `Ctrl` + `Tab`. One other cool feature is navigating back and forth to the code points by `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Left` and `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Right`. One more option is to label some points in code you want to refer frequently (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `1`) and then navigate to them from other files by (`Ctrl` + `1`).